# disable scroll on mouse click in Midnight commander's mcview

Tags: mouse, scrolling, midnight-commander

I use Midnight commander and it's mcview a lot to browse log files. I often want to use mouse to select text and copy it, but if I click in the text mcview will scroll. I tried to disable it by unchecking the scroll options, but it has no effect in mcview 
[image]
is it possible to disable mouse click scrolling easily ?

Comment: Are you aware that you can use 'shift+mouse selection' to copy and paste text?

Comment: I know, I sometimes forget not to click, and when I do click in long log file, it scrolls rapidly into middle of nowhere